# Tkinter matplotlib canvas updates too slowly for real time data

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, real-time

I am working with a device that sends 100 readings per second and I want my GUI to have a plot of this data showing the last 300 points collected. However, I have found that:

1. appending a new data point to the y-axis queue
2. clearing the plot that exists already
3. plotting the new data list
4. redrawing the canvas

after each point takes nearly 0.2 - 0.4 seconds, which is incredibly slow.

This is the code I am using currently. A while loop keeps checking a queue, and once a new element is pushed to it, it calls `update` with the element as a parameter. Would anyone be able to suggest some improvements to the efficiency or alternatives to matplotlib?

```
class GraphFrame:
    def __init__(self,root,channel,index):
        self.root=root
        self.frame=tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
     
        self.y = Queue(maxsize = 300)
        
        self.fig, self.axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
        self.axes.plot(list(self.y.queue))

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)

    def update(self, new_point):
        if self.y.full():
            self.y.get()
        self.y.put(new_point)
        self.fig.axes[0].clear()
        self.fig.axes[0].plot(list(self.y.queue))
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Edit: managed to solve the issue using blitting for matplotlib and replacing the Tkinter canvas with a label with the image of the Graph. Will try to upload code on github and link it.

Comment: instead of clear the figure and build from scratch, you should modify the line artists.

Comment: Can you post a list of representative data? Maybe like 15 - 25 data points?

Comment: where is `Queue` imported from?

Comment: @PaulH data points are just floating point readings from a sensor. Values are around 2000 when nobody is in front of it and 20,000 when someone stands in front of it. Nothing too special just floating point numbers.

Comment: @PaulH ```from queue import Queue```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of rebuilding your figure for each new point, I would modify the LineArtist you already have.

```py
class GraphFrame:
    def __init__(self,root,channel,index):
        self.root=root
        self.frame=tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
     
        self.y = Queue(maxsize = 300)
        
        self.fig, self.axes = plt.subplots(1,1)

        # capture the artist
        self.line, = self.axes.plot(list(self.y.queue))

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)

    def update(self, new_point):
        if self.y.full():
            self.y.get()
        self.y.put(new_point)
        
        # update the artist
        self.line.set_xdata(list(range(len(self.y))))
        self.line.set_ydata(list(self.y.queue))
```

Comment: self.line is a list, it gives "list object has no attribute set_xdata"
Edit: nevermind, I just got the first element of that list [0]

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa did you include the comma in the assignment? If so, you might just need to extract out the first (and only?) element from that list.

Comment: ok, self.y is a queue, so I cant use len(), so I used .qsize() instead. The graph doesnt visually update, and when I resize the GUI, it updates, but only shows a vertical line at x = 0.00 and y = 0 - 0.04+

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa oh there probably needs to be a `self.fig.draw()` after the ariststs are updated

Comment: ```self.fig.draw()``` gives ```draw_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument : 'renderer'```. Also, keep in mind this is a plot in a tkinter FigureCanvasTkAgg not just a regular matplotlib plot.

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa can you set up a more reproducible example?

Comment: An GraphFrame object is created, then a loop keeps polling a queue, and when the queue has an element, it gets that element and calls the update function with that element as a parameter. The loop breaks when a flag is set to false. That is all that is happening.

Comment: I understand that, but I can't really run your code as is, so anything I (or anyone else) suggests is just shooting from the hip. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am limited to how much code I can show as the rest is company code. So, if possible, can you just show me how to use bilting to update a matplotlib graph faster? This should be enough.

Comment: Nvm, managed to resolve the issue. See edit on question.